# View translation path

Tags: 7, views, path-aliases, i18n-l10n

I have a View with an path like **example.com/en/news**. I translated the view with Views translation. Works like a charm. But how and where do I translate the path to something like **example.com/de/neues**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to use [i18n_page_views](http://drupal.org/project/i18n_page_views) module - it is a display plugin that installs an item labeled `i18n page` into the **+Add** (display) button menu. It's like a `page` display extended by fields for entering a path for each enabled language.

While it does not offer any tool to convert existing displays into i18_page type, it's quite easy to do that manually - just export your existing view(s), change the type of the display in a notepad and re-import w/override.

Regretfully, the module does not offer UI for creating translated menu items - this also has to be done manually.

At any rate, it's advisable to bind all translation paths (created manually as jdu suggested, or created automatically) into a translation path set (`admin/config/regional/i18n_translation/path/add`). I found that without it the `i18n_get_path_translations` function worked whimsically.

Answer (score 1):

a very simple way would be to add a new alias yourself by accessing "/admin/config/search/path"

however, if you have translation set up correctly, that path should already exist.  I think maybe your translation set up is done in a non-standard way.  could you describe it in detail?

Comment: I think this is still a very simple way to translate view paths.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Path Translation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1279392) module.